# I would like to invite a methode in another class within a Form class. How do I transfer the Form object to the external method as a parameter?

Tags: c#

In the following example I look for the solution:
The Form_Users -form contains a tapPage control (its name be: tabControl1), which has several additional contol (such as TextBox, ComboBox, etc.).
From the SayRecordtoForm () method (this method is another part of the class, AccessDBOperations) I want to invoke the Test_getbankcreate (C) method just to have its parameter tabControl1.

When I released this assignment:

```
Control_name = tabpage_object.Controls [0] .Controls [1] .Name
```

This does not work in the Test_getbankcreate method :-( .But if I get this assignment in the SayRecordtoForm () method, it works there:

```
Control_name = tabControl1.Controls [0] .Controls [1] .Name
```

What is the reason why I can not pass the Form tabControl1 control and can not reference it?

```
namespace Cameleons_FrameWork_1._0
{
    public partial class Form_Users : Form
    {
        public Form_Users() 
        {
            FuO = new AccessDBOperations();
            SayRecordtoForm();
        }

        private void SayRecordtoForm()
        {
            FuO.Test_getbankcreate(tabControl1);
        }
    }
}

namespace FrameWorkClassLib_Algorim
{
    public class AccessDBOperations
    {
        public void Test_getbankcreate( object tabpage_object )
        {
            string controll_name = tabpage_object.Controls[0].Controls[1].Name
        }
    }
}
```

Can this be done at all?

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work?" you should mention the error, any way, why using object? use the actual type of the `control`, I am not sure what do you mean by it, but just use its actual type, not its parent type `object`.

Comment: Change the method from private to public.

Comment: Thanks for your idea. It was the trouble I was careless and not Object, but TabControl's name was :-(!
I can not see the wood from the tree! :-)